# Producing a Hash of a File

Tags: web3js, dapp-development, javascript

I would like to upload a file to my UI and then produce a hash of it so I could later store it on Ethereum. Here is the code I am using to upload the file:

```
<div>
   <label for="file input">Submit your file here</label>
   <input type="file"">
</div>
```

How can I create a hash of any file on the UI side so I can later submit this hash onto Ethereum?

Comment: Please take your time to get acquainted with some implementation of web3 (web3.js probably most suitable in this case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to write and deploy a simple storage smart-contract (with solidity and truffle), then you need to use the web3js library to connect to the blockchain and later to call your function in the smart-contract --> `send a transaction to upload the hash of the file in your deployed smart contract`

The web3 library provide a function to calcuate the hash of a given string so you should read your file as string or convert it somehow to string and call `web3.utils.keccak256(string)` to get the hash